# CSS3 grid layouts: New row after specific element - possible?

Tags: css, css-grid

I've got a list of items, sorted by date.

Some of the items are in the future (green items), thus more interesting, some are in the past (brown items). I want the second group of items to start in a new row.

```css
.grid{
  width: 120px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.item{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
.brown{
  background:brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
</div>
```

The number of overall items / items per category is constantly changing, the number of Items per row depends on screen size - that might eliminate some possible solutions to this.

I could of course split the array containing all items at a certain point and organize the output into two separate grids, like so:

```css
.grid{
  width: 120px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}
.item{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
.brown{
  background:brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
</div>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
</div>
```

Probably that's the easiest option. Looks like what I want to achieve & isn't too difficult to do. But anyway, I'm curious: Is there a more elegant approach to this? I was thinking something like:

```
.item.green + .item.brown:before { 
/* force new row */
}
```

Comment: So how is no one talking about how HTML things #a52a2a is brown...?? I though my eyes were broken looking at these examples.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You could target the first `.brown` after `.green` and set [grid-column-start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start) to 1.

```css
.grid {
  width: 120px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.brown {
  background: brown;
}

.green + .brown {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Since you are using `grid-template-columns`, you won't be able to acheive this with `before` or `after`, you would need to set the `grid-column-start` to 1 with the  `item.green + .item.brown` selection:

```css
.grid{
  width: 120px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.item{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.green{
  background:green;
}
.brown{
  background:brown;
}
.item.green + .item.brown { 
    
    grid-column-start: 1;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
  <div class="item brown"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The approach that I came up with is definitely the longest one, but if for what ever reason you need to have a modular design I think this way would save you time in the end. Added grid-areas and added individual class for all your tiles.

```css
.grid{
width: 120px;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
grid-template-areas: "green1 green2 green3"
                     "green4 green5 green6"
                     "green7 green8 green9"
                     "brown1 brown2 brown3"
                     "brown4 brown5 brown6";
grid-gap: 10px;
}

.item{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.green1 {
  background:green;
  grid-area: green1;
}
.green2 {
  background:green;
  grid-area: green2;
}
.green3 {
  background:green;
  grid-area: green3;
}
.green4 {
  background:green;
  grid-area: green4;
}
.green5 {
  background:green;
  grid-area: green5;
}
.brown1{
  grid-area: brown1;
  background:brown;
}
.brown2{
  grid-area: brown2;
  background:brown;
}
.brown3{
  grid-area: brown3;
  background:brown;
}
.brown4{
  grid-area: brown4;
  background:brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item green1"></div>
  <div class="item green2"></div>
  <div class="item green3"></div>
  <div class="item green4"></div>
  <div class="item green5"></div>
  <div class="item brown1"></div>
  <div class="item brown2"></div>
  <div class="item brown3"></div>
  <div class="item brown4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a very scalable approach. What if in the future there are 20 items? What if there are 100?